Android libs.versions.toml shows convention plugin dependecies as not being used when they are
I have migrated my current Android application to employ libs.versions.toml and convention plugins via a build-logic module based on the NowInAndroid application
it all works as expected, however i have a concern that the libs.versions.toml file shows the dependencies that are being used at compile time in my convention plugins and those provided by the plugins themselves are highlighted as not being used.
is there anyway i can prevent this message being shown inside the libs.versions.toml file?

heres the code within my compose convention plugin
dependencies {
    val bom = libs.findLibrary("compose-bom").get()
    add("api", platform(bom))
    add("androidTestImplementation", platform(bom))
    add("api", libs.findLibrary("compose-preview").get())
    add("debugApi", libs.findLibrary("compose-tooling").get())
}

this is the convention plugins build script snippet
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.JvmTarget

plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}


java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

kotlin {
    compilerOptions {
        jvmTarget = JvmTarget.JVM_17
    }
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly(libs.agp)
    compileOnly(libs.firebase.crashlytics.plugin)
    compileOnly(libs.kotlin.composePlugin)
    compileOnly(libs.kotlin.plugin)
    compileOnly(libs.android.tools.common)
    compileOnly(libs.symbol.processing.gradle.plugin)
    compileOnly(libs.room.plugin)
}


If you use something alike this, it is broken:
val bom = libs.findLibrary("androidx-compose-bom").get()
add("implementation", platform(bom))

One probably can consider it useless complexity - which the BOM is intended to reduce. Basically one can hide the yellow marker with #noinspection GradleDependency, but it's still questionable.

the compileOnly is set for the convention plugins build script as show in my edited answer

My bad, these are plugins, which won't be packaged anyway.
